# Change contents of one HTML page from another HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a.html and b.html and I want to change a div element from a.html using a button created in b.html. How can I do that?

a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to RemoteDemo</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Tvspace">
        <iframe id ="frame" width="560" height="315" src="someRandomURL" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>     
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Remote</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id = "next"> Next </button>
    <!--When I click this button I want the src to change-->
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this but this only works if the button is on a.html

```
$("#next").click(function(){
            $("#frame").attr("src", "anotherRandomURL");
        })
```

Comment: You can do DOM manipulation in iframes with `<iframe element>.contentDocument`, although I'm not sure how to use jQuery for that

Comment: did you means copy element/content from other page?

Comment: not copying from any other page

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: This answer was assuming that b.html is embedded within a.html as an iframe. Based on comments from the OP it appears that is not the case.

If a.html and b.html are actually opened in different browser windows/tabs, there are a couple of possible work-arounds.

- The best would be to insert a server in the process. This is probably a good place for WebSockets (especially for a.html). On b.html you would have a websocket or ajax that would trigger from the click event. Then the server would contact a.html over an open WebSocket to notify it of the click, and you could have JavaScript to change the iframe src.
- Depending on the browser it might also be possible to create a browser plugin. Probably not a good solution though.

#### Original answer assuming b.html was in an iframe on a.html

This only works if your iframe is not cross-origin (see [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy))

in a.html, i'm assuming your src is b.html:

```
    <iframe id ="frame" width="560" height="315" src="b.html" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

in b.html, do something like this script:

```
<body>
    <button id = "next"> Next </button>
    <script>
        var btn = document.querySelector('#next');
        btn.onclick = function(e){
            var pdoc =  window.parent.document;
            var frame = pdoc.querySelector('#frame');
            frame.src = 'watch.txt';
            var div = pdoc.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
            pdoc.body.append(div);
        };
     </script>
</body>
```

Working with jQuery across frames is possible, but you have to keep in mind that the two frames would both need to have the jQuery library included as a script tag.

Comment: the src in a.html is a youtube URL. when  I click the button in b.html another URL will load at the same place

Comment: So I gather that a.html and b.html are running in different browser tabs/windows? Maybe on the same computer, maybe on different computers? I modified my answer to address this scenario, if that's what you meant.